# Lambda Except Placement

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to return a list of `LANS` and I want to exclude `UserInformation.Globals.LANID` from the list.

Code:

```
var LANlist = _context.CORP_MatrixPositionOLDWay
               .Where(x => x.ChildOrgLevel.StartsWith(ParentORG.ToString()))
               .Select(x => x.ChildLAN)
               .Except(UserInformation.Globals.LANID);
```

Error:

> 'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Except'

Comment: [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) takes two enumerables. Is `UserInformation.Globals.LANID`  an  `IEnumerable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to exclude this single `ChildLAN`, use `Where`:

```
var LANlist = _context.CORP_MatrixPositionOLDWay
           .Where(x => x.ChildOrgLevel.StartsWith(ParentORG.ToString()))
           .Select(x => x.ChildLAN)
           .Where(lan => lan != UserInformation.Globals.LANID);
```

Comment: Thank you so much good sir! It didn't even cross my mind to use a "Where !=". Always trying to do things the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

You can still achieve it with Except, just pass in an IEnumerable:

```
var LANlist = _context.CORP_MatrixPositionOLDWay
           .Where(x => x.ChildOrgLevel.StartsWith(ParentORG.ToString()))
           .Select(x => x.ChildLAN)
           .Except(new[] { UserInformation.Globals.LANID });
```